# torch tensor assignment do not work when using multi mask

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor and mask. Moreover, I have a second mask.

Now I want a change value of tensor[mask][second_mask], but it does not work.

I think it is becuase tensor[mask] return a new tensor rather than a view of the origin tensor, and apply value to tensor[mask][second_mask] will not change values of the origin tensor. My demo is like below:

```
import torch

x = torch.linspace(1,9,9).reshape((3,3))
mask = x>5
second_mask = 0 # In practice, it will be a booltensor
x[mask][second_mask] = 100
print(x)

# One way to solve it is use a temp tensor be like:
t = x[mask]
t[second_mask] = 100
x[mask] = t

# but it is sooooo long, hoping for any convenient method
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indices instead of mask for that:

```
import torch

x = torch.linspace(1,9,9).reshape((3,3))
mask_idx = torch.where(x > 5) # tuple of 1D tensors for x,y coordinates
second_mask = 0 # this is index in my understanding instead of mask, but I follow the given naming convention

# make final_mask_idx using x, y coordinates and second_mask
final_mask_idx = (mask_idx[0][second_mask], mask_idx[1][second_mask])

x[final_mask_idx] = 100
```

Comment: I think it will be an better way to do that than use a temporary tensor.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that what's returned by the select operation will not be a view.

Since your second mask is just the index `0`, not really a mask, are you always trying to update the first positively-masked value? If so, for that case you could do something like:

```
>>> x = torch.linspace(1,9,9).reshape((3,3))
>>> x.flatten()[ mask.to(torch.int).argmax() ] = 100
>>> x
tensor([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5., 100.],
        [  7.,   8.,   9.]])
```

When all the max values are the same, `argmax` returns the first of them. Unfortunately it's not implemented for bool, hence the `to(torch.int)`.

Comment: I write second_mask = 0 for short. In practice, it will be a booltensor, so this method may not well?

Comment: yeah in that case your 'but it is sooooo long' method is probably best. You could do something to get indexes, but IMO that'll be less readable and clear.